# Root document is not readable

Tags: errors, miktex

I'm receiving this message "Root document is not readable" when I try to run a document that I've created in TeXworks. (MiKtex)

The document type is a report and has several pages of tables with figures, and equations.

I've ran this document and it has worked fine before. I don't think I have made any changes to the code so that this could occur.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Solved,

I simply copied all of the code into a new blank document and then it worked!